# What is the difference between a database and simply a key-value pair?

Tags: database, nosql, rdbms

In a very basic scenario (perhaps a web-app), using a large database like MySQL is over-kill. What bothers me the most is that in node.js, I can write a solution in less-code than it would take to use the drivers.

```
var content = [];
setInterval(60000, function(){ 
  fs.writeFileSync("database.db", JSON.stringify(content));
});
```

Now, this solution seems elegant enough, if not perhaps a little bit of lag (due to the mere fact JSON is huge). But what I really want to understand is how would a large system like MySQL be better than simply using, say, an array. (I'm assuming we're not looking at 1 Gigabyte data sets, merely something simply with key-value pairs, something small enough to manage directly in the apps memory.

More so, what functionality does a database have as opposed to something like NoSQL? How difficult would it be to add this type of functionality to an app like the pseudo-code pictured above?

Comment: "what functionality does a database have as opposed to something like NoSQL?" - Most NoSQL solutions ARE databases!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databases aren't magic. You could implement everything they do in your own software. But why would you?

Databases can give you a lot of features for free, which would take a lot of effort to implement and test yourself:

- Automatic persistence of data to hard drive the moment it is changed
- Automatic handling of concurrent access by multiple processes
- Automatic caching of frequent data requests
- Automatic plausibility checking of your data (through constraints)
- Search indices for faster lookup of data
- Query languages allow you to do filtering and transformation of data
- Frameworks for ad-hoc data analysis

But when you have no need for any of that, storing all your data in your own flatfile format is always an option.

Answer (score 0):

The risk you run with the above code is that if two people update the database at the same time, your entire database is likely to be destroyed ("concurrancy"). Even the slightest bug in the code (e.g. accidentally setting `content` to `[]`) will leave you without data.

NoSQL-type databases will protect you from that - updating a record wrong may destroy the record, but at least you have the rest of your records.

Relational databases also add inter-record constraints. NoSQL reduces the need for this by having very complex records, but if you have, for example, a family tree, and every person is a record, I don't think there is any way to have references between two people that are enforced (if person "A" is the child of person "B", then person "B" MUST be the parent of person "A", AND you can look up records in either direction).

NoSQL, especially simple key-value pairs, are a lot simpler, which tends to have huge advantages - speed, load balancing and redundancy become simpler, etc., so this is a trade-off.

Comment: I still have trouble understanding the benefit of relational-dbs--could't you store the whole family tree as a record?

Comment: You want to store, where possible, each "item" of information separately, so updates only update a small number of records. Also, if two users want to update two different people at the same time, it's not a problem - they are different records. If the whole family tree is one record, they can't update at the same time.

Comment: I see, but if I added some safe-gaurds to the code, would it be at all secure?

Comment: For a very small scale web app, you can get away with it. I have done it myself. Don't forget to back up though! And expect your app to slow down as the amount of data increases. A few hundred records will work, larger amounts will slow down.

Comment: @bobbybee sure you could add some safe-guards against that. You could also implement your own caching layer, your own system for incremental changes, your own library of search indices and so on. But in the end you will end up with spending weeks of work on creating a (bad) clone of existing database solutions.